# Countup in time frame

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to count up (a timer of some sort) to the number **2112** between now and tomorrow (March 30 at 21:12PM EST)! I've googled but I'm not sure how to go about it. The plugins/codes I've seen are just countdown plugins which have seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {
//custom 'this' selector
thisEl = $(this); 

// array of custom settings
var settings = { 
'date': null,
'format': null
};

// append the settings array to options
if(options) {
$.extend(settings, options);
}

//create the countdown processing function
function countdown_proc() {
var eventDate = Date.parse(settings.date) / 1000;
var currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
callback.call(this);
clearInterval(interval);
}

var seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

var days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); 
//calculate the number of days

seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; 
//update the seconds variable with number of days removed

var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; 
//update the seconds variable with number of hours removed

var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
seconds -= minutes * 60; 
//update the seconds variable with number of minutes removed

//conditional statements
if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

//logic for the two_digits ON setting
if(settings.format == "on") {
days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
}

//update the countdown's html values.
thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
}

//run the function
countdown_proc();

//loop the function
interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);
};

}) (jQuery);



//Provide the plugin settings
$("#countdown").countdown({
//The countdown end date
date: "30 March 2016 21:12:00",

// on (03:07:52) | off (3:7:52) - two_digits set to ON maintains layout consistency
format: "on"
}, 

function() {
// This will run when the countdown ends
$( ".flash" ).addClass( "show" );
$( "ul#countdown" ).addClass( "hide" );
$( ".black" ).addClass( "new" );


});
```

This returns 01 Days, 30 Hours, 10 Minutes 5 Seconds.

I really just want 4 numbers, 2112. How can it be done, nautical time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic count up script would look like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/gogusr61/)

```
var second = 1000; // ms
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
   if (i < 2112) {
      i++;
      console.log(i);
   } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
   }
}, second); // <- You'd change this second to some other value.
```

Then you'd have to take tomorrow's date:

```
var maxTime = Date.parse('Wed Mar 30 2016 21:12:00 EDT');
```

And today's date:

```
var timeNow = Date.now();
```

And subtract the difference:

```
var timeDiff = maxTime - timeNow;
```

By formatting it back to a new date, you can play with the JS Date Object's methods to adjust the timer to your specific needs (AKA "nautical time")

```
var dateDiff = new Date(timeDiff);
console.log(dateDiff.getMinutes());
```

See the JS Date Object API Docs at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Then change the `second` value, at the bottom of that code. It will increment based on whatever amount of time that is passed into it. So if you want 2112 equal parts of time between now & tomorrow, then you'd divide `timeDiff / 2112` & feed those results into that value.

*Important note:* If you do that, then your time increments would be longer than someone else's time increments, when they loaded the code after you finish writing it & testing it out. So you'll have to play with the date object, to figure out what your time increments should be. I recommend making them static & not dynamic. (Avoid using `timeDiff / 2112` as the interval).